# How to Split 1 Word Away From a Delimiter Word

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation where I am pulling data from SAP and then breaking this up and filing a report. Unfortunately, the data I am pulling is made by multiple people across varying countries and as such, the format is slightly different with each. While the phone numbers and names change, it seems that they always list "Phone" followed by the number. I would like to split after this number however and take everything below it. Is there a way to split a statement 1 word (Or character string) up from the delimiter chosen, in this case "Phone"?

```
08.08.2018 19:51:54 UTC "Person's Name" (CODE) Phone +##########
Reporter is the pharmacist. She states a patient reported her Device will not work, and if she is able to get it to work no medication comes out. Patient is an experienced user of The medicine. Pharmacy to replace to patient. Company to replace to pharmacy. Pharmacy to return product.
09.08.2018 11:47:16 "Person's Name" (Code) Phone +##########
On 09-AUG-2018, Company received 1 Device from lot #######, 07-2019, 09.08.2018 20:36:32 UTC "Person's name" (Code) Phone +##########
```

Comment: a = Split(s, "Phone") will produce an array split by phone

Comment: Please include the code you already have otherwise your question is too broad to give a detailed answer.

Comment: I  understand that I can split at "Phone", however I would like to split beginning one word up from "phone" which will be a variable phone number. Also, I have not code for this as I have never done something beyond the standard format

    A=Split(Description,"Phone")(1)

Comment: You can do the work with strings, finding the location of the + and then keeping the entire string from that loc through the string length, IF your data string always ends in the phone number.  Is that what you want?  The phone number?  Split is useful but I rarely use it.

Comment: I want everything beyond the phone number (not including the phone number) could you provide some form of example code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you want everything after the Phone number, in you sample none of them have anything after the phone number, but this code will print everything after the phone number from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

```
Sub GetMyText()
    cnt = 0 'number of cells containing string "Phone"
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange 'change this line based on the Sheet name you have
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Phone") > 0 Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            a = Split(cell.Value, "Phone")
            b = Trim(a(1)) 'get the second part and remove the leading and trailing space
            pos = InStr(b, " ") 'find the first space
            If pos > 0 Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cnt, 1).Value = Right(b, Len(b) - pos) 'change the name of the sheet if needed or have sheet names Sheet2
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```